# Why does /proc/mounts show a line with 7 columns (type overlay)?

Tags: docker, fstab, overlayfs

I am trying to troubleshoot https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/12047, which seems to happen because one of the lines in the output of `cat /proc/mounts` inside a Docker container of mine seems to be very special: it has 7 columns, not 6.

Here is what that line looks like:

```
rootfs overlay / overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/PPDEP2NMRVDPT5KD5MWUXRVCC7:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/74ZMIOZ4PCTUODVBBM5HPKA2VD:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/OI4LL4AG2CMZFQ2NOBA4WAGO2D:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/XNVOJIJBXWDYAMHKQVV36C75V7:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/OV7JOV3TW5MJUIXZ3D5INLWP2S:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/HESJLWTHRG6WS3ATRQZ53LHTHR:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/APVFQLQRINYD73WECQN5743O64:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/4XZCFLNC4XES6EMPFMVIDVCDZG:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/QXPY3J5KFA225KY2UQ2ZMSFQL6:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/J2FZIZQJRJILGLDETPYG3LUO36:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/6SQYUEBL4UYK7LOSPVWHY2VSTO:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/HEM6EMXICNYBE7NFCL66QLRN7F:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/FKCJWEQK6MTE7ZGGAQKRIIAQ2S:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/2CQEUDLJPSF5QYSHUP3FZZP2NG:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/RPHBJZTVMCPKW5YO4DLXDDEMG6:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/7CK3YF2F3UPMWJEDMJSPF4BUVM:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/6VNPYNFDWXULE3DHTTOKVK4TEV:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/FHGM5ZCKKZXU3ILXNLACVEEVJV:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/QTUW3G342VYWBSHCJKOUFBW67D:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/NUWVWRCIWNNIPY6HFOFLS7PUMK:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/7GGMDSIT66JJAT7WXHJKYZ5YZT:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/XWKJI2UXVR27CWTCN5EH7BB6UH:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/BMY5J7APK7EU25PJFBSRH2Q34L,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7a60705c89c815e9c7df7a76ebc7aa10a7c9c8f82d6cba59f193542753bd1570/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7a60705c89c815e9c7df7a76ebc7aa10a7c9c8f82d6cba59f193542753bd1570/work,index=off,xino=off 0 0
```

Is that format normal? The `overlay` after `rootfs` looks like it shouldn't be there, according to `man 5 fstab`. Why is there an extra word?

Comment: The first column is the device name. Unfortunately it's possible for the device name to contain a space, in which case `/proc/mounts` cannot be parsed unambiguously. It's unusual, but possible; a common case is remote filesystems (e.g. NFS or Samba) whose name contains a space. Here it looks like the (pseudo) device name is `rootfs overlay` instead of the usual `rootfs`.